# 40G QSFP+ to 4x10G SFP+ Cable

Tags: cisco, layer1, cable

I need to buy a Direct attach 40G QSFP+ to 4x10G SFP+ Cable that may be used to connect two FPGA boards.

I can find reasonably priced cables, however the cables are usually "branded". Is it important from the point of view of connection to the MGT in Xilinx (or maybe Intel/Altera)?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource3 recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: That's not what they're asking. The real question is "what difference does branding make", which Zac67 has answered.

Comment: @RickyBeam Seconding that.

Comment: Removed the requests for product recommendations.

Comment: @RickyBeam, the questions asking for the safest brand and the best documented were off-topic. I removed those questions.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.

The "branding" is necessary on many network devices with vendor lock-in - they accept only SFP transceivers with the expected vendor mark. It's unlikely the Xilinx interface checks for these.

Technically, the branding doesn't change any other property of the cable. So, if a certain vendor compatibility isn't required it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `%GBIC_SECURITY_CRYPT-4-VN_DATA_CRC_ERROR: GBIC in port Gi1/0/49 has bad crc`
`%PHY-4-UNSUPPORTED_TRANSCEIVER: Unsupported transceiver found in Gi1/0/49` There are ways to make it work, but it'll aways spit out those "errors"

Comment: @RickyBeam The OP was asking about Xilinx interfaces and given their nature it's unlikely they're locked in.